# getting trouble with .value in javascript

Tags: javascript

JS

```
function validate() {
    var cb = document.getElementById("cmbs").value; alert=(cb);
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return validate()">          

    <label>company/business name</label><br>       
    <input type="text" name="companybusiness_name" placeholder="company/business Name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="cmbs" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: Fix your post please , it would be easier to read. plus explain what are you trying to do

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the error you get?

Comment: Hi, thanks for adding the code, please also add a description of your problem and what you have tried so ar

Comment: `alert(cb)` maybe?

Comment: M trying to get value of input tag in alert

Comment: when you console.log(cb), there's no value in cb?

Comment: .value is not working

Comment: value is working fine , check my answer please

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validate() {
    var cb = document.getElementById("cmbs").value; alert(cb)
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return validate()">          

    <label>company/business name</label><br>       
    <input type="text" name="companybusiness_name" placeholder="company/business Name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="cmbs" value="">
    <button type="sumbit">
    ok
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did it help you ?

Comment: No its still same problem

Comment: it's working here on snippet , did you copy my answer ?